# Cannot connect Spring Boot with Cloud SQL using spring cloud gcp starter

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Spring Boot newbie trying to get my app hosted on GCP AppEngine Flexible with Cloud SQL (mysql), second generation.

Using the Spring Cloud GCP starters that I got from here:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-sql-sample, I am trying to get my local spring boot app to connect to Cloud SQL. When trying to run the SQLApplication on my local Tomcat, I am getting:

```
2018-07-28 20:57:35.663  INFO 66641 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2018-07-28 20:57:36.730 ERROR 66641 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create socket factory 'com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory' due to underlying exception: 
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.createSocketFactory(MysqlIO.java:3411) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:303) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2482) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2519) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2304) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar:na]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:346) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:123) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:365) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:534) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:151) [spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115) [spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78) [spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:46) [spring-jdbc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:210) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.createSchema(DataSourceInitializer.java:104) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker.afterPropertiesSet(DataSourceInitializerInvoker.java:64) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:224) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1015) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:339) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:334) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(DataSourceInitializerPostProcessor.java:55) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:439) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1712) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1133) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1256) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1133) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.SqlApplication.main(SqlApplication.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.createSocketFactory(MysqlIO.java:3408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar:na]
    ... 95 common frames omitted
```

The only changes I have made to this project are to application.properties. I've authenticated using gcloud as well.

Here is my application.properties, doesn't work:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=sqldemo
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=Project:Region:Instance
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.username=myuser
spring.datasource.password=mypass
```

I've tried to add mysql socket factory directly to pom.xml, but didn't work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.10</version>
</dependency>
```

I've made sure that my SQL API is enabled. 
Thank you!

Comment: What if you trying running this command. `$ mvn clean jetty:run -DINSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME=instanceConnectionName -Duser=root -Dpassword=myPassword -Ddatabase=myDatabase` I understand you are already trying to run it without the part after `-`.

Comment: Please always write a Project Id as `[MY_PROJECT_ID]`. This is a sensitive private data

Comment: Additionally please share your `pom.xml`

Comment: pom.xml is in the code I referenced: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/master/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-sql-sample/pom.xml

Comment: I am running it from a Cloud Compute instances and I don't have any errors. Could you provide the full trace so that we can have more context?

Comment: Can you include the full exception stack trace? There might be a causing exception somewhere there. You do not need to setup any proxy. Please make sure that you have Cloud SQL API enabled as described in the reference doc:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_prerequisites

Comment: @MikeE. I've added a stack trace and made sure that Cloud SQL API is enabled. Thank you!

Comment: `com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory` is still somehow not in your classpath despite adding the `mysql-socket-factory`. I would guess that something is going on with your app packaging or deployment. Are you deploying a WAR to your local Tomcat after building it with Maven? If so, open up that WAR as a ZIP file and make sure that the `mysql-socket-factory` JAR is there. You might also be deploying via the IDE, and a number of things could go wrong there as well.

Comment: @MikeE. I get the same thing when running `mvn clean compile spring-boot:run` as well.

Comment: @Rosalind Maybe you can share the complete `pom.xml`, or even better a sample app that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to setup Cloud SQL Proxy. 
As you can see in [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) :

> Note that you do not need to use the proxy or configure SSL to connect to Cloud SQL from App Engine standard or flexible environment. These connections use a "built-in" proxy implementation automatically.

With App Engine Java, [Cloud SQL Socket Factory](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory) is behind the scene to make the jdbc connection without any IP address, just instance name.

It seems like this library was not found or there is an issue when new instance is created.

Please check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tfalvo/a5e6dff5f602c90f26f12e0d0ed3c0c2) with pom.xml and application.properties.

Comment: I was able to just add spring.datasource.password=WhatEverMyPassword
 , but wonder will it expose this password to external world ?

Answer (score 1):

I have had also problems with starting spring-cloud-gcp-sql-sample, I managed to run it with following pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-samples</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-sql-sample</artifactId>
    <name>Spring Cloud GCP SQL MySQL Starter Code Sample</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

  <repositories>
    <!-- Use Spring Milestone Repository -->
    <repository>
      <id>repository.spring.milestone</id>
      <name>Spring Milestones Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RC1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

and application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=[your-server-name]
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=[your-database-name]

# So app starts despite "table already exists" errors.
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true

# Enforces database initialization
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

# Leave empty for root, uncomment and fill out if you specified a user
spring.datasource.username=root

## Uncomment if root password is specified
spring.datasource.password=root

server.port = 80
```

I've authenticated using gcloud.
I am running this sample with spring-boot:run

Answer (score 1):

Before config spring, you must enable cloud sql admin api

Create json in credentials with role:

```
Cloud SQL > Cloud SQL Client
Cloud SQL > Cloud SQL Editor
Cloud SQL > Cloud SQL Admin

kubectl create secret generic cloudsql-instance-credentials --from-file=credentials.json=file_name.json

kubectl create secret generic cloudsql-db-credentials --from-literal=username=ethan --from-literal=password=12345678 --from-literal=dbname=clash_royale --from-literal=connectname=projectid:region:instance-name
```

Two way connect to gcloud sql, it works perfectly

1. CLOUD SQL PROXY

config file deployment.yaml

```html
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ template "fullname" . }}
  labels:
    draft: {{ default "draft-app" .Values.draft }}
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}"
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        draft: {{ default "draft-app" .Values.draft }}
        app: {{ template "fullname" . }}
{{- if .Values.podAnnotations }}
      annotations:
{{ toYaml .Values.podAnnotations | indent 8 }}
{{- end }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
        image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
        env:
          - name: DB_HOST
            value: 127.0.0.1:3306
          # These secrets are required to start the pod.
          # [START cloudsql_secrets]
          - name: DB_USER
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: cloudsql-db-credentials
                key: username
          - name: DB_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: cloudsql-db-credentials
                key: password
          # [END cloudsql_secrets]
      # Change <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME> here to include your GCP
      # project, the region of your Cloud SQL instance and the name
      # of your Cloud SQL instance. The format is
      # $PROJECT:$REGION:$INSTANCE
      # [START proxy_container]
      - name: cloudsql-proxy
        image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.11
        command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy",
                  "-instances=PROJECT:REGION:INSTANCE=tcp:3306",
                  "-credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json"]
        # [START cloudsql_security_context]
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 2  # non-root user
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
        # [END cloudsql_security_context]
        volumeMounts:
          - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
            mountPath: /secrets/cloudsql
            readOnly: true
      # [END proxy_container]
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: {{ .Values.probePath }}
            port: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
          initialDelaySeconds: {{ .Values.livenessProbe.initialDelaySeconds }}
          periodSeconds: {{ .Values.livenessProbe.periodSeconds }}
          successThreshold: {{ .Values.livenessProbe.successThreshold }}
          timeoutSeconds: {{ .Values.livenessProbe.timeoutSeconds }}
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: {{ .Values.probePath }}
            port: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
          periodSeconds: {{ .Values.readinessProbe.periodSeconds }}
          successThreshold: {{ .Values.readinessProbe.successThreshold }}
          timeoutSeconds: {{ .Values.readinessProbe.timeoutSeconds }}
        resources:
{{ toYaml .Values.resources | indent 12 }}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {{ .Values.terminationGracePeriodSeconds }}
      serviceAccountName: {{ .Values.service.name }}
      # [START volumes]
      volumes:
        - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
          secret:
            secretName: cloudsql-instance-credentials
      # [END volumes]
```

pom.xml

```html
    <!-- DATABASE-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

application.properties

```html
#database=mysql
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://${DB_HOST}/{$DB_NAME}?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

2. WITHOUT PROXY

deployment.yaml

```html
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ template "fullname" . }}
  labels:
    draft: {{ default "draft-app" .Values.draft }}
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}"
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        draft: {{ default "draft-app" .Values.draft }}
        app: {{ template "fullname" . }}
{{- if .Values.podAnnotations }}
      annotations:
{{ toYaml .Values.podAnnotations | indent 8 }}
{{- end }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
        image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
        volumeMounts:
          - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
            mountPath: /secrets/cloudsql
            readOnly: true
        env:
          - name: DB_HOST
            value: 127.0.0.1:3306
          # These secrets are required to start the pod.
          # [START cloudsql_secrets]
          - name: DB_USER
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: cloudsql-db-credentials
                key: username
          - name: DB_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: cloudsql-db-credentials
                key: password
          - name: DB_NAME
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: cloudsql-db-credentials
                key: dbname
          - name: CONNECT_NAME
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: cloudsql-db-credentials
                key: connectname
          # [END cloudsql_secrets]
      # Change <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME> here to include your GCP
      # project, the region of your Cloud SQL instance and the name
      # of your Cloud SQL instance. The format is
      # $PROJECT:$REGION:$INSTANCE
      # [START proxy_container]
#      - name: cloudsql-proxy
#        image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.11
#        command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy",
#                  "-instances=",
#                  "-credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json"]
#        # [START cloudsql_security_context]
#        securityContext:
#          runAsUser: 2  # non-root user
#          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
#        # [END cloudsql_security_context]
#        volumeMounts:
#          - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
#            mountPath: /secrets/cloudsql
#            readOnly: true
      # [END proxy_container]
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: {{ .Values.probePath }}
            port: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
          initialDelaySeconds: {{ .Values.livenessProbe.initialDelaySeconds }}
          periodSeconds: {{ .Values.livenessProbe.periodSeconds }}
          successThreshold: {{ .Values.livenessProbe.successThreshold }}
          timeoutSeconds: {{ .Values.livenessProbe.timeoutSeconds }}
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: {{ .Values.probePath }}
            port: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
          periodSeconds: {{ .Values.readinessProbe.periodSeconds }}
          successThreshold: {{ .Values.readinessProbe.successThreshold }}
          timeoutSeconds: {{ .Values.readinessProbe.timeoutSeconds }}
        resources:
{{ toYaml .Values.resources | indent 12 }}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {{ .Values.terminationGracePeriodSeconds }}
      serviceAccountName: {{ .Values.service.name }}
      # [START volumes]
      volumes:
        - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
          secret:
            secretName: cloudsql-instance-credentials
      # [END volumes]
```

pom.xml

```html
  <!-- DATABASE-->

  <!--<dependency>-->
   <!--<groupId>mysql</groupId>-->
   <!--<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>-->
  <!--</dependency>-->

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

application.properties

```html
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=${CONNECT_NAME}
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=${DB_NAME}
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json

# So app starts despite "table already exists" errors.
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true

# Enforces database initialization
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
```

I hope it help for you.

Comment: Under resources have you put your secrets.yml ? and deployment.yml so ?

Comment: Yep, I put it in secret.yaml

Comment: @EthanNguyen thanks for you description. I followed your example (with proxy) but I got the error ```Warning  FailedMount  14s (x7 over 45s)  kubelet, gke-gara-cluster-default-pool-673744a2-n377  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "cloudsql-instance-credentials" : secrets "cloudsql-instance-credentials" not found```. I just created cloudsql-db-credentials. I have also to create the file with the same credentials for the volume ?

Comment: In my case, I had to put `spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=${DB_NAME}` in first place in `application.property`. Rest was untouched. Hope these would help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should setup a proxy

See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy